# I want to append several div after button click using jquery

Tags: jquery

But each div contains title like: div-1, div-2, div-3 sequentially. As many times I click the button for div appears, the title needs to display sequentially. Thanks in advance. Here is my code:

```
    <div class="productDiv">
    </div>
    <div class="mt-3 text-center">
     <button class="btn profile-button" style="color: white" type="button" 
         id="btnAddtoList">Add Product</button>
    </div>

    $(function() {
    var divCount = 0;
      $('#btnAddtoList').click(function(){
      divCount++;
      var newDiv = $(
        `<div class=item-wrapper-${divCount}>` +
          '<div class="container rounded bg-white mt-3 mb-3">' +
             '<div class="row">' +
                '<div class="col-md-12">' +
                    '<div class="row mt-3">' +
                        '<span><strong>
                           Div Number #<span id="num"></span>
                            </strong></span>' +
                     '</div>' +
                     '<div class="row mt-1">' +
                         '<select class="product_option form-control" 
                            id="product" data-search="true">' +
                              '<option disabled selected>Select</option>'+
                         '</select>' +
                     '</div>' +
                     '<div class="row mt-3">' +
                       '<label class="labels" style="font-size: 16px">
                         Product Name
                        </label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                           id="productName">' +
                     '</div>' +
                     '<div class="row mt-3">' +
                       '<label class="labels" style="font-size: 16px">
                         Sell Price
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                         id="sellPrice">' +
                     '</div>' +
                     '<div class="row mt-3">' +
                        '<label class="labels">Amount</label>
                         <input type="number" class="form-control" 
                         id="amount">' +
                      '</div>' +
                      '<div class="mt-3 d-flex flex-column align-items- 
                      center 
                        text-center">
                          <button class="btn btn-danger deleteItem" 
                            type="button">Delete</button>
                       </div>' +
                  '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
              '</div>' +
          '</div>');
           $('.productDiv').append(newDiv);
           console.log(divCount);
           document.getElementById("num").innerText = divCount;
        });
    });
```

As many times I click the button for div appears, the title needs to display sequentially. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I appended div, but the title is not displayed sequentially.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a [mcve] of the problem with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for:

```js
let counter = 0;
$('.button').on('click', function(){
  counter++;
  const div_title = 'div-'+counter;
  $('.container').append('<div>'+ div_title +'</div>');
})
```

```css
.container{
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">Append DIV</button>
<div class="container"></div>
```